# Some public beta‘s have ~0 views suddenly

Tags: bug, area-51, beta-sites

Health.SE apparently has 1 view/day, according to Area51 (given that multipler users were active just minutes ago, this seems rather unlikely), Pets and Latin Language are even down to nil.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Pictures are just proofs in case this can’t be replicated)

- eosio.SE has 328 visits/day, seems legit
- Bioinformatics, IoT, SiteCore,  have 1 visit/day
- Monero has 3 visits/day
- all other sites have  0 visits/day

<sup>So far, I went until Latin Language in the Area51 tab, then I got rate limited [This IP address has performed an unusual high number of requests and has been temporarily rate limited.]</sup>